# CONDITION STATEMENT IN ACCESS REPORT

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

How to set condition if else statement in report access?

This is the coding for search specific data in the report.....

```
Dim lngID As String
lngID = InputBox("Enter RF No")
If lngID = "" Then
DoCmd.ClearMacroError
Else
DoCmd.OpenReport "Requisition_ReportComplete", acViewReport, , "[RF_no]=" & lngID
End If
```

And this is the coding for the if else statement

```
Dim lngID As String

lngID = InputBox("Enter RF No")
If lngID = "" Then
DoCmd.ClearMacroError
ElseIf lngID <> RF_no Then
MsgBox "Data not exist"
Else
DoCmd.OpenReport "Requisition_ReportComplete", acViewReport, , "[RF_no]=" & lngID
End If
```

The if else statement for search are not working with what I want..and I don't know why....

Answer (score 0):

I am making an assumption that RF_no is Reference Number and is a primary key. Your code will work fine if RF_no is only ONE specific number that you define it before the If statement. One way you could check to see if the record exists in the table before opening the form would be to use Dcount or Dlookup ie:

```
ElseIf DCount("SomeField", "YourTable", "RF_no=" & lngID) = 0 Then

ElseIf IsNull(DLookup("[Some Field]", "YourTable", "[RF_no] = " & lngID)) Then
```

Either one should work fine. They will check to see if a record exists in your table with the ID = lngID and will open up the the form if nothing is found.

Comment: How about if the record doesn't exist if I put the RF_no in lngID which is input box? Did I need to use the <> to determine the RF_no exist or not? @Roberth